# Updating a Highchart from a form with a click() event in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, highcharts

I have a chart that I would like to update whenever a form on the same page is submitted. The `var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options)` expression works fine by itself (it draws a chart). When I put it inside the callback function for the `.click()` event, when I click the corresponding submit button, the updated plot flashes on the screen for a second and is then erased and replaced by the original plot.

I'm so close to doing what I need to, but I'm stumped by this. Thanks for your help.

Libraries:

```
<link type="text/css" href="css/cupertino/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />      
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/highcharts.js"></script>
```

Here is the Javascript:

```
<script>
  $(function() {
$("#lines").val(),colors: $("#colors").val(),},
var options = {
    chart : {
        renderTo : 'container',
        defaultSeriesType: 'line',
        zoomType: 'xy' },
    title : { text : 'Foo' },
    xAxis: { title: { text: 'x label'  } },
    yAxis: { title: { text: 'y label' } },
    series : {}
}
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
    $( "#submit" ).click(function() {
    options.series = [{"name": 10402, "color": "rgba(255,139,0,0.5)", "data": [[ 146,55.8 ],[150,60.9]]},{"name": 10403, "color": "rgba(255,255,0,0.5)", "data": [[ 130,25.8 ],[150,54.9]]}];
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
    });

  });
  </script>
```

Here is the HTML body:

```
<body>
<form name="chartform" id="chartform">
<input type="submit" id="submit" /><br />
</form>
<div id="container" style="width: 100%; height: 800px"></div>
</body>
```

This is driving me nuts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is working fine for me:

```
var chart;
$(document).ready(function() {
    options ={ 
        chart: {
         renderTo: 'container',
         defaultSeriesType: 'line',
         zoomType: 'xy'
      },
               title : { text : 'Foo' },
                xAxis: { title: { text: 'x label'  } },
    yAxis: { title: { text: 'y label' } },

        series: {}
              };

   chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
   series3 = [{"name": 10402, "color": "rgba(255,139,0,0.5)", data: [[ 146,55.8 ],[150,60.9]]},{"name": 10403, "color": "rgba(255,255,0,0.5)", "data": [[ 130,25.8 ],[150,54.9]]}];
   series2 = [{
         name: '1042',
         color: "rgba(255,139,0,0.5)",
         data: [[ 146,55.8 ],[150,60.9]]
      }, {
         name: '10403',
          color: "rgba(255,255,0,0.5)",
         data: [[ 130,25.8 ],[150,54.9]]
      }];
    $( "#chartform" ).submit(function() {
    options.series = series3;
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
return false;
    });


});
```

**EDIT:** I believe the problem is that you are submitting the form. Do a return **false** and use submit handler instead of click.  You can check it live in: http://jsfiddle.net/bCFHL/157/

Comment: @f1r3br4nd You are right. The problem was in another part. What I updated should work!

Comment: Okay, I finally got mine to run. If I put the `<input type="submit">` button inside a `<form>` then the problem happens. If I put it anywhere outside, it works. Conversely, if I put your `<input type="submit">` inside a form, your version develops the same problem mine had! This makes no sense whatsoever.

Comment: @f1r3br4nd My version is working fine. Notice that I've changed the handler. You can put the submit button inside the form if you force the handler of submit to return false.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I still don't understand why forms do this, but at least this is a workaround.