# creating highcharts with form submit event

Tags: php, highcharts

In my dashboard i have 2 charts created using [highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/) . one chart is displayed automatically on load another chart want to change according to the values selected in the drop down box.

I am using php to get the database values according to the drop down box selection. and passing it t0 java script to generate the chart.

my problem is it doesn't  showing the second chart .

here is my code:

```
    var chart1;
      //$(document).ready(function() {
      $("#chartvalue").submit(function() {
       var su=<?php echo json_encode($_SESSION['successcalls']) ?>;
var fail=<?php echo json_encode($_SESSION['failurecalls']) ?>;
var da=<?php echo json_encode($_SESSION['datename']) ?>;
alert(su);
chart1 = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'chartmon_div',
        defaultSeriesType: 'line',
        marginRight: 130,
        marginBottom: 25
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Call Details',
        x: -20 //center
    },
    subtitle: {
        x: -20
    },
    xAxis: {

        categories: da
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Total calls'
        },
        plotLines: [{
            value: 0,
            width: 1,
            color: '#808080'
        }]
    },
    tooltip: {
        formatter: function() {
                return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+
                this.x +': '+ this.y ;
        }
    },
    legend: {
        layout: 'vertical',
        align: 'right',
        verticalAlign: 'top',
        x: -10,
        y: 100,
        borderWidth: 0
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Success',
        data: su
    }, {
        name: 'Failure',
        data: fail
    }]
            });
        });
            //});
            </script>
```

i have the php variales code in form submit

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8795986/updating-a-highchart-from-a-form-with-a-click-event-in-jquery
Maybe this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

encrypt your javascript of highchart with PHP condition

```
<?php if(isset($_POST['variable'])) {
foreach ($productname as $prdkey => $prdval){
    foreach ($typecount as $typekey => $typeval)
    {
        switch ($typeval) {
            case 0:
                if($producttotal[$prdval][0] != '')
                {
                  $pricecustomstr .= round($producttotal[$prdval][0]).', ';
                  //$pricecustomtotal = $pricecustomtotal + $producttotal[$prdval][0];  
                }
                else
                {
                  $pricecustomstr .= '0, ';     
                }
                break;

            case 1:
                if($producttotal[$prdval][1] != '')
                {
                  $priceuploadstr .= round($producttotal[$prdval][1]).', ';
                  //$priceuploadtotal = $priceuploadtotal + $producttotal[$prdval][1];
                }
                else
                {
                  $priceuploadstr .= '0, ';     
                }
                break;

            case 2:
                if($producttotal[$prdval][2] != '')
                {
                  $pricepredefinedstr .= round($producttotal[$prdval][2]).', ';
                  //$pricepredefinedtotal = $pricepredefinedtotal + $producttotal[$prdval][2];  
                }
                else
                {
                  $pricepredefinedstr .= '0, ';     
                }
                break;

            default:
                if($producttotal[$prdval][0] != '')
                {
                  $pricecustomstr .= round($producttotal[$prdval][0]).', '; 
                }
                else
                {
                  $pricecustomstr .= '0, ';     
                }
                break;
        }
    }

}

$productstring;
$pricecustomstr = rtrim(trim($pricecustomstr),', ');
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
// highchart js code
plotOptions: {
                    series: {
                        stacking: 'normal'
                    }
                },
                    series: [{
                    name: 'Custom Design',
                    data: [<?php echo $pricecustomstr; ?>]
                }, {
                    name: 'Upload Design',
                    data: [<?php echo $priceuploadstr; ?>]

            });
</script>
<?php } ?>
```

Thanks

Comment: i have updated the code above.the problem is it showing when i click the submit button and it hide after that

Comment: can you give me the value of the su , fail and da ?

Comment: da 's value is [4,15],and fail value is [1,0],su value is [0,1]